# Is it possible to combine unit tests into a list?

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of unit tests (Test1, Test2, etc.), but rather than having them run automatically, I'd like to do something similar to the following:

```
List<Test> tests = {
    Test1,
    Test2,
    Test3,
    ...
}
```

The goal of doing so is to be able to comment out/uncomment (enable/disable) swaths of tests easily to isolate the ones in which I'm immediately interested.

Is that possible, or am I stuck with adding/removiong [disabled] tags to every test header?

Comment: Which test framework are you using?

Comment: I'm new to C#, so please pardon the crummy answer.
I just right click -> generate tests; is there a standard package? (I didn't install anything extra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio allows creation and running of Test Lists.  Just pick **Test -> Create Test List...** from the menu.  You can then run just the tests in any particular list you've defined.

Comment: Wow.  Never even noticed there was a "Test" menu item.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If NUnit is an option, you can use the [`TestCaseAttribute`](http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5).  ReSharper really ties this in well with Visual Studio.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010710/4068), MSTest doesn't support this.